# SQL IF - ELSE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a table like this :

```
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID    | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| view  | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Is it possible to do this with SQL's IF-ELSE statement ?**

1. Check if there is ID=1 row in table
2. If there is , increase view column by 1 .
3. If there isn't, insert new row to table with ID=1

It should be something like this :

```
IF((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM wp_viewcount WHERE ID=1) == 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO wp_viewcount VALUES (1,1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE wp_viewcount SET view=view+1 WHERE ID=1
END
```

Comment: You'll need a `where` clause in the update bit.

Comment: @JonEgerton , still syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SQL statement will result in the IF - ELSE logic you want, by using the `on duplicate key` syntax.

```
insert into wp_viewcount values(1,1) on duplicate key update view=view+1;
```

Comment: this is merely implementation of Andomar's suggestion

Comment: a single statement is almost always faster than a stored procedure and doesn't carry the memory requirement. Procedures are helpful for multiple executions or dynamic input

Answer (score 2):

You can only use MySQL's `if` in a stored procedure.  For example:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure` (IN wp_id INT)
BEGIN
IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_viewcount WHERE id = wp_id)<1) THEN
    INSERT INTO wp_viewcount(id,view) VALUES (wp_id,1);
ELSE
    UPDATE wp_viewcount SET view=view+1 WHERE ID=wp_id;
END IF;
END //
```

Given your use case, you might be better served by MySQL's [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: can you add `UPDATE` , too. please.

Comment: Added, do consider the "duplicate key" option.  You can do this without an `if` statement.

Comment: I'd expect the `duplicate key` option to perform better.  If you want to be sure, measure!

Comment: `on duplicate` => 0.0583 - `procedure` => 0.0009 . But `on duplicate` is better for one-time using, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
if not exists (select * from wp_viewcount where id = 1)
begin
    --insert logic
end
else
begin
    --update logic
end
```